# whats the difference between {% vs {%- in twig?

Tags: twig

as can be seen here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig
some of the `if` conditions are written as:

`{% if condition %}`

but others are written as:

`{%- if condition -%}`

my code works perfectly fine with both versions.
unfortunately its impossible to google the answer as google doesn't like no alphanumeric chars in query very much, also i did not find any reference in twig documentation.

my question is, whats the difference between those two?

whats the meaning of the dash in `{%-` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is related to twig's whitespace control. By using the whitespace control modifier on your tags, you can trim leading and/or trailing whitespace. [Here are the docs.](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#whitespace-control)

Comment: Please be aware that as of Twig versions 1.39 and 2.8.0 upwards now also feature `{%~`. This whitespace control code removes the spaces but keeps new lines. [Here's the source.](https://symfony.com/blog/better-white-space-control-in-twig-templates)